# How to erase line drawn on a uiimageview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I would like to erase lines drawn in touch event in a uiimageview.
I thought to call setNeedsDisplay in touchesEnded but it doesn't work.

In Canvas.m I have :

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    self.location = [touch locationInView:self];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInView:self];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, location.x, location.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, currentLocation.x, currentLocation.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    location = currentLocation;
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution - save the original image at the beginning and when you want to erase the lines just do `self.image = savedImage`

However, much better solution (with better performance) would be to not changing the image at all but having a transparent view over the `UIImageView` and draw inside it. The drawing could also be much simpler (e.g. having a `CGImageRef` buffer instead of creating an image context everytime by `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`).